# How to add a label to the border of a div and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple thank you screen with text in the border. The current css I have now works for a fixed screen but when changing size of it, it is not responsive and becomes out of place. Here is my css and component. I am using react js to implement this screen.

```
.thankYouParent {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouBox {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 75vw;
    justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouText {
    font-family: interstateBold;
    font-size: 10vw;
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
}

.borderText {
    font-family: interstateRegular;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vh;
    background-color: black;
    align-self: flex-end;
    bottom: -25px;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-right: 1vw;
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "../css/ThankYou.css"

export default function ThankYou(){
    return(
        <div className="thankYouParent">
            <div className="thankYouBox">
                <label className="borderText"> For visiting us </label>
                <label className="thankYouText">Thank You</label>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Correct look:
[image]

After changing screen size:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the text uses the `vh` unit, and is related to the height of the page. The position should also be related to the height - `bottom: -1.5vh;`. However, we need to consider the width of the border by using `margin-bottom: -3px;`.

```js
function ThankYou(){
  return(
    <div className="thankYouParent">
      <div className="thankYouBox">
        <label className="borderText"> For visiting us </label>
        <label className="thankYouText">Thank You</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThankYou />,
  root
)
```

```css
.thankYouParent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouBox {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 75vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thankYouText {
  font-family: interstateBold;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
}

.borderText {
  font-family: interstateRegular;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
  bottom: -1.5vh;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: aside your great answer, i would advise to mixe px and vh/vw value for the font-size , to avoid text to become too small or too big .  possible example : `.borderText { font-size: calc(6px + 1vw);}`.